# GLOBAL vs normal Ruby SDK in Intellij Idea or RubyMine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, intellij-idea, rubymine

When working on a Ruby project in Intellij/RubyMine you have to select what Ruby SDK you want to use.  My dropdown currently looks like this.

[image]

What is the difference between 2.1.1, 2.1.1[global], and 2.1.1[my-project-name]?

Why would I want to use one over the other?

Answer (score 2):

The names in the brackets are actually not created by IntelliJ/RubyMine. Rather they are created by RVM: they are the names of RVM gemsets. RVM lets you create multiple sets of gems by creating named gemsets. The global gemset is created by default and is shared by all the other gemsets. The rest of the named gemsets were either manually or automatically created (by a .ruby-gemset file, for example). IntelliJ picks up on the Rubies and gemsets managed by RVM and creates an SDK entry for each Ruby/gemset combination.

The reason you would use one of the SDKs that correspond to a named gemset is if you've installed gems specific to that project inside that gemset. If you are not using gemsets to manage your Rubygems then you can just use one of the Ruby SDKs without a gemset name in brackets.

For more information about gemsets you can see the RVM documentation here: https://rvm.io/gemsets/basics